# Which sentence is correct? (mesmerize)

Tags: sentence-construction, tense

I am writing a letter for my  friend. Which sentence is correct?

> Every time I look  into your alluring eyes, I melt and ***get mesmerized*** by your eyes.
>
> Every time I look  into your alluring eyes, I melt and ***got mesmerized*** by your eyes.
>
> Every time I look  into your alluring eyes, I melt and ***am mesmerized*** by your eyes.
>
> Every time I look  into your alluring eyes, I melt and ***mesmerized*** by your eyes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first and third sentences are correct. There is a very subtle difference in meaning between the two. The *get* implies the eyes themselves play an active role in your mesmerisation, whereas *am* is more passive on the role of the eyes themselves.

It's the slightest of nuances (which I daresay would be lost on most people anyway) and it would not be mistake to use either one over the other. I personally like the third sentence the best.